# Action on clicking a button 10 times in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a link type of thing in a website which opens another webpage after clicking it 10 times. Someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance !

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll probably want a variable to track the number of clicks, and a click event handier on the link element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```js
var count = 1;
function myFunction() {
  if (count<10) {
    count++;
  }
  else {
    window.location = "your-target-page.html";
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me 10 times</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean only open after clicking it 10 times, I think you want to create a "fake" link that triggers some JS function, which keeps track of a running counter. Then when the counter hits your number 10, trigger the window.open or whatever window you wanted.

Comment: I'll try that. I'm learning JavaScript so I'm not sure I can do that....... can you please give me a code snippet to help.